# How to move from one C/C++ function to the next (both directions)

Tags: vim

I just want to jump to from one function to the next in .c/.cpp files. How do I do that?

Comment: java / C++ methods http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128678/vim-go-to-beginning-end-of-next-method (must be enclosed on a top `class {}`), beginning of function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109503/how-to-jump-to-the-beginning-of-a-function-body-in-vim

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `]]` which jumps to the next `{` char on the first column.

There are similar options, just try `:help ]]` for more information.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the use of [[ and ]], note the following from motion.txt in the vim docs:

```
If your '{' or '}' are not in the first column, and you would like to use "[["
and "]]" anyway, try these mappings:
   :map [[ ?{w99[{
   :map ][ /}b99]}
   :map ]] j0[[%/{
   :map [] k$][%?}
```

Comment: The problem with these is that if you have a search active and you use these maps, your search will be overwritten.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use `]m` to jump to the next method, `[m` to jump to the previous method.

In your `~/.vimrc`, you can do

`nnoremap ]m ]mzz`

`nnoremap [m [mzz`

so that everytime you jump between methods, you put the method at the center of your screen.

Answer (score 3):

I use these mappings which will make [[ and ]] work with functions that don't put the starting { at the beginning of the line.

```
map ]] :call search("^\\(\\w.*\\)\\?{")<CR>
map [[ :call search("^\\(\\w.*\\)\\?{", "b")<CR>
map ][ :call search("^}")<CR>
map [] :call search("^}", "b")<CR>
```

Comment: Huh, make the cursor to the end of the match which is '{' or '}' like `map ]] :call search("^\\(\\w.*\\)\\?{", "e")<CR>` maybe better.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at exuberant-ctags it works with Emacs, and your "vim" thing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use taglist, I added a feature that does just that. You can jump from one tag to the other using Ctrl-up & Ctrl-down, provided the language is supported by taglist.

Here: https://github.com/man9ourah/taglist

and this to your `.vimrc`.

```
nmap <silent> <c-up> <plug>(TlistJumpTagUp)     " Map ctrl-up to move one tag up
nmap <silent> <c-down> <plug>(TlistJumpTagDown) " Map ctrl-down to move one tag down
```