# How to jump to the beginning of the current function body in Vim?

Tags: vim

As title, if I'm in the middle of function body and the function body is very long, how can I jump back to the beginning of the function body .

Answer (score 113, accepted):

[[m](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%5Bm)

> Go to [count] previous start of a method

Works for Java or similar structured languages, and for Python as well.

Comment: And for React/ES6/JavaScript class methods as well :-)

Comment: But only works for methods, not functions (needs enclosing `class {}`). :-( Method specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128678/vim-go-to-beginning-end-of-next-method

Comment: Very nice. My precious.

Comment: To add, for procedural languages like C the following combo will bring you to the beginning of the function `[m[{`, then you could map it to something like `[f`.

Answer (score 46):

**C language `[[`**

If your C code is in the non-Egyptian style:

```
[[
```

`[m` only works if you have an enclosing `{}` around the function, e.g. `class { method(){} }` for Java / C++.

And this is a good bet that works for both Egyptian and non-Egyptian braces:

```
?^[^ \t#]
```

Examples:

```
void egypt() {
#define DONTCARE 1
    int indented code = 1;
}

void tpyge()
{
#define DONTCARE 1
    int indented code = 1
}
```

Comment: For Egyptian (or Kernigan-Richie) style, `[{` might be of help as well.

Comment: `[m` seems to work for me from inside an out-of-line method definition in C++... with no outer {} from a class definition or namespace.

Comment: @dgrogan on the example above, vim 8.0 Ubuntu 18.04 `-u NONE`, `]m` stops at closing braces. Things become worse if there are braces inside the function, e.g. `if {}`.

Comment: Alternatively, if the folding structure is defined in your file, `[z` / `]z` might work.

Answer (score 37):

For functions contained in a pair of curly-braces {}:

Jump to beginning: `[{`

Jump to end: `]}`

Replace the curly-blackets by parens or square-brackets for functions that use those.

Comment: No idea why you got downvoted - but this worked for me with Go.

Comment: This does not jump to the begining of the function when you are inside nested `{}` blocks. `[m` is the way to got (think: go to last member)

Comment: @BalintG. `[m` has the same effect as `[{` for me.

Comment: @Geremia then you are not inside a nested block.

Comment: @BalintG Yes, I was.

Comment: @Geremia Ok. Maybe not vanilla? The doc for `[{` states _Go to previous unmatched '{'._.

Comment: @BalintG. That's what both `[{` and `[m` do for me, when I'm inside a `while {…}` which is inside a C function. It must consider a `while` statement a "method": "`[m     Go to [count] previous start of a method (for Java or similar structured language).`"

Answer (score 9):

I spent hours to make this pattern: **`/^\s*\(\i\+\_[ \t\*]\+\)\+\i\+\_s*(\_[^)]*)\_s*{`**, it works good for me.

**EDIT**: a better pattern(version 2): **`/\(\(if\|for\|while\|switch\|catch\)\_s*\)\@64<!(\_[^)]*)\_[^;{}()]*\zs{`**

**see the effect here:**
[image]

you can map some convenient **bindings** in your .vimrc, such as:

```
" jump to the previous function
nnoremap <silent> [f :call search('^\s*\(\i\+\_[ \t\*]\+\)\+\i\+\_s*(\_[^)]*)\_s*{', "bw")<CR>
" jump to the next function
nnoremap <silent> ]f :call search('^\s*\(\i\+\_[ \t\*]\+\)\+\i\+\_s*(\_[^)]*)\_s*{', "w")<CR>
```

**EDIT**: a better pattern(version 2):

```
" jump to the previous function
nnoremap <silent> [f :call
\ search('\(\(if\\|for\\|while\\|switch\\|catch\)\_s*\)\@64<!(\_[^)]*)\_[^;{}()]*\zs{', "bw")<CR>
" jump to the next function
nnoremap <silent> ]f :call
\ search('\(\(if\\|for\\|while\\|switch\\|catch\)\_s*\)\@64<!(\_[^)]*)\_[^;{}()]*\zs{', "w")<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks works great for me! The only one I've found so far that even works with C++ namespaces

Answer (score 5):

In 2022, [treesitter](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/) deserves your attention.

The built-in `[m` uses lexical rules and always jumps to the previous `{` position or the outermost `{` position.

In contrast, treesitter takes advantage of syntactic information, so it can jump to a more precise position, and there are no limitations as described below:

> The above two commands assume that the file contains a class with methods.
> The class definition is surrounded in '{' and '}'.  Each method in the class
> Each method in the class is also surrounded with '{' and '}'.  This applies to the Java language.
> file looks like this: >

If you want to learn more, check https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-textobjects

Answer (score 1):

BTW, the only relatively sure way to be able to do this is to modify vim, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635770/jump-to-function-definition-in-vim)

[edit]
and this only works with languages supported by exuberant ctags.  Since we've not been deigned fit to know which language you wish to do this in, it's possible that this answer will not be correct either.
[/edit]

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got moving around blocks and paragraphs in code sorted you might like to look at what you can do when you're in the middle of those blocks by looking at [this part](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#text-objects) of the vim doc's.

Things like delete the block, insert before the block, append after the block, etc.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

Searching (backwards) for `?^{` should normally get you there.

Comment: Are there really "so many cases where this can go wrong"? The question specifically ask from "in the middle of function body", and when writing C code it should be a very non-standard coding style for a function not starting with '{' at the beginning of a line as well as  having some line within the function also starting with '{'.

Comment: @vincentleest only if you are not inside a `{}` block already in C / C++.